# How do you organise your git repositories?

Tags: version-control, git

I'm struggling to phrase this question correctly, hence the poor title.

Basically I have a simple Chrome extension that I am developing for work. It is in use at the moment and as I am using it regularly I am constantly thinking of improvements or extra features it could have.

My file structure is like this (I'm on a mac)

`~/Sites/Chrome_extensions/{my employers name}/CharCounter/`

`CharCounter/` contains all the files needed for the Chrome extension.

Whenever I am happy with a new version of my extension I pack it in Chrome and the resulting .crx file is called `CharCounter_{version number}.crx`

So for example, the most recent is called `CharCounter_1.3.3.crx`. However, the development folder currently always has the same name. If I want to roll back and continue developing a previous version I can't.

I have decided to start using git however I'm unsure how to tackle my version control.

Should I set up my git repository in

`~/Sites/Chrome_extensions/{my employers name}`

then when I decide I am making a big enough change to the extension to warrant a new version number I duplicate the CharCounter folder and add `_{new version number}` to it? Thereby having several CharCounter folders each with a different version number appending to them.

or should I set it up in

`~Sites/Chrome_extensions/{my employers name}/CharCounter/`

and never duplicate the CharCounter folder but just make a new commit every time I make a new version?

How do you tackle version control? Does using git do away with having to keep multiple versions (current and legacy) of your code in folders called `folder_version_X.Y.Z` or is that still a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution would indeed be tags, perhaps something that might get what you want is to (partially) implement a workflow as illustrated [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

To make it easier to work with such a workflow a git extension has also been made which can be found [here](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow)

This would allow you to:

- Switch back to a previous version if that needs some bug fixing
- Work on multiple new features at the same time (If this ever occurs)
- Make sure you always have a fully working branch

Answer (score 3):

The later.

Create a new repository for every project. When you build a version you want to [create a tag](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html) for it.

Comment: Thanks for the tag link, that's not something I've come across before.